# XPath to recursively remove empty DOM nodes?

Tags: php, dom, xpath

I am trying to find a way to cleanup a bunch of empty DOM elements from an HTML source like this:

```
<div class="empty">
    <div>&nbsp;</div>
    <div></div>
</div>
<a href="http://example.com">good</a>
<div>
    <p></p>
</div>
<br>
<img src="http://example.com/logo.png" />
<div></div>
```

However, I don't want to harm valid elements or line breaks. So the result should be something like this:

```
<a href="http://example.com">good</a>
<br>
<img src="http://example.com/logo.png" />
```

So far I have tried some XPaths like this:

```
$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);

//$x = '//*[not(*) and not(normalize-space(.))]';
//$x = '//*[not(text() or node() or self::br)]';
//$x = 'not(normalize-space(.) or self::br)';
$x = '//*[not(text() or node() or self::br)]';

while(($nodeList = $xpath->query($x)) && $nodeList->length > 0) {
    foreach ($nodeList as $node) {
        $node->parentNode->removeChild($node);
    }
}
```

Can someone show me the correct XPath to remove empty DOM nodes that serve no purpose if empty? (img, br, and input serve a purpose even if empty)

Current output:

```
<div>
    <div>&nbsp;</div>

</div>
<a href="http://example.com">good</a>
<div>

</div>
<br>
```

### Update

To clarify, I am looking for an XPath query that is either:

- Recursive in matching empty nodes until all are found (including parents of empty nodes)
- Can be successfully run multiple times after each cleanup (as shown in my example)

Comment: Two points: 1) since some of the top-level nodes you want to remove are not actually *empty* (they have child nodes and one of them has a non-breaking space entity in it, which is technically actual content) you will have to keep running the query over and over until there are none left (which you seem to have realised) which is potentially *very* computationally expensive if there are a lot of deeply nested levels to remove. 2) Removing empty nodes is not necessarily always safe. It is liable to break CSS rules that rely on these elements for correct spacing and floating.

Comment: @DaveRandom, good point, I hadn't thought about the CSS rules. However, for my use-case that is not a problem - neither is the extra computational time. These DOM structures are not for display to the user. The while loop seems to be stopping while there are still DOM elements left to purge.

Comment: What output is it producing at the moment? Which nodes are left that you want to be removed?

Comment: @DaveRandom, I added the exact output.

Comment: Realistically after playing around with it I don't think there is any way to do this with the simplistic XPath approach you are using. You will need to just take all nodes and loop them, and test them against various rules according to what you want to remove/keep. Something like [this](http://viper-7.com/psBBqf).

Comment: Xeoncross, **XPath is a *query* language for XML documents**. As such, the evaluation of an XPath expression only selects nodes or extracts non-node information from the XML documen, but never alters the XML document. Thus evaluating an XPath expression never deletes or inserts nodes -- the XML document remains the same.
This means that evaluation of an XPath expression never deletes or inserts nodes -- the XML document remains the same. Therefore, the wanted processing canot be done only with an XPath expression. An XSLT solution is simpler and elegant as compared with an imperative PL one.

Comment: @Xeoncross, ok, you didn't answer but I'll post my solution anyway

Comment: @Xeoncross, I have updated my answer (at its very end) with a single XPath expression that selects all nodes that can be deleted in one "round" -- without the need for "multiple cleanups".

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**I. Initial solution:**

**XPath is a *query* language for XML documents.** As such, the evaluation of an XPath expression only selects nodes or extracts non-node information from the XML documen, but never alters the XML document. Thus evaluating an XPath expression never deletes or inserts nodes -- the XML document remains the same.

**What you want is "to cleanup a bunch of empty DOM elements from an HTML source" and cannot be done with XPath alone**.

This is confirmed by the most credible and the only official (we say *normative*) source on XPath -- the **[W3C XPath 1.0 Recommendation](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#section-Introduction)**:

> "*The primary purpose of XPath is to address parts of an XML [XML]
>   document. In support of this primary purpose, it also provides basic
>   facilities for manipulation of strings, numbers and booleans. XPath
>   uses a compact, non-XML syntax to facilitate use of XPath within URIs
>   and XML attribute values. XPath operates on the abstract, logical
>   structure of an XML document, rather than its surface syntax. XPath
>   gets its name from its use of a path notation as in URLs for
>   navigating through the hierarchical structure of an XML document.* "

**Therefore, some additional language must be used in conjuction with XPath in order to implement the require functionality**.

XSLT is a language especially designed for XML transformation.

**Here is an XSLT - based example -- a short and simple XSLT transformation that performs the requested cleanup**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
  <xsl:copy>
   <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
  </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match=
 "*[not(string(translate(., '&#xA0;', '')))
  and
    not(descendant-or-self::*
          [self::img or self::input or self::br])]"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When applied on the provided XML** (corrected to become wellformed XML document):

```
<html>
    <div class="empty">
        <div>&#xA0;</div>
        <div></div>
    </div>
    <a href="http://example.com">good</a>
    <div>
        <p></p>
    </div>
    <br />
    <img src="http://example.com/logo.png" />
    <div></div>
</html>
```

**the wanted, correct result is produced**:

```
<html>
   <a href="http://example.com">good</a>
   <br/>
   <img src="http://example.com/logo.png"/>
</html>
```

**Explanation**:

1. The identity rule copies "as-is" every node for which it is selected for execution.
2. There is a single template, overriding the identity template for any element (with the exception of `img`, `input` and `br`), whose string value from which any `&nbsp;` has been removed, is the empty string. The body of this template is empty, which effectively "deletes" the matched element -- the matched element isn't copied to the output.

---

**II. Update**:

The OP clarifies that he wants one or more XPath expressions that:

> "*Can be successfully run multiple times after each cleanup.*"

**Interestingly enough, there exists a single XPath expression that selects exactly all nodes that need to be deleted -- therefore "multiple cleanups" are completely avoided**:

```
//*[not(normalize-space((translate(., '&#xA0;', ''))))
  and
    not(descendant-or-self::*[self::img or self::input or self::br])
    ]
     [not(ancestor::*
             [count(.| //*[not(normalize-space((translate(., '&#xA0;', ''))))
                         and
                           not(descendant-or-self::*
                                  [self::img or self::input or self::br])
                          ]
                    )
             =
              count(//*[not(normalize-space((translate(., '&#xA0;', ''))))
                      and
                        not(descendant-or-self::*
                                 [self::img or self::input or self::br])
                        ]
                   )
              ]
          )
     ]
```

**XSLT-based verification**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

 <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
  <xsl:copy>
   <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
  </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match=
   "//*[not(normalize-space((translate(., '&#xA0;', ''))))
      and
        not(descendant-or-self::*[self::img or self::input or self::br])
       ]
        [not(ancestor::*
               [count(.| //*[not(normalize-space((translate(., '&#xA0;', ''))))
                           and
                             not(descendant-or-self::*
                                    [self::img or self::input or self::br])
                             ]
                      )
               =
                count(//*[not(normalize-space((translate(., '&#xA0;', ''))))
                        and
                          not(descendant-or-self::*
                                 [self::img or self::input or self::br])
                          ]
                      )
               ]
            )
        ]
 "/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When this transformation is applied on the provided (and made wellformed) XML document (above), all nodes are copied "as-is" with the exception of the nodes selected by our XPath expression**:

```
<html>
   <a href="http://example.com">good</a>
   <br/>
   <img src="http://example.com/logo.png"/>
</html>
```

**Explanation**:

Let us denote with `$vAllEmpty` all the nodes that are "empty" according to the definition of "empty" in the question.

`$vAllEmpty` is expressed with the following XPath expression:

```
   //*[not(normalize-space((translate(., '&#xA0;', ''))))
     and
       not(descendant-or-self::*
             [self::img or self::input or self::br])

      ]
```

For all of these to be deleted, we need to delete just the "top nodes" from `$vAllEmpty`

Let us denote the set of all such "top nodes" as: `$vTopEmpty`.

`$vTopEmpty` can be expressed from `$vAllEmpty` using the following XPath 2.0 expression:

```
$vAllEmpty[not(ancestor::* intersect $vAllEmpty)]
```

this selects those nodes from `$vAllEmpty` that don't have any ancestor element that is also in `$vAllEmpty`.

The last XPath expression has its equivalent XPath 1.0 expression:

```
$vAllEmpty[not(ancestor::*[count(.|$vAllEmpty) = count($vAllEmpty)])]
```

**Now, we replace in the last expression `$vAllEmpty` with its expanded XPath expression as defined above and this is how we obtain the final expression, that selects only the "top nodes to delete":**

```
//*[not(normalize-space((translate(., '&#xA0;', ''))))
  and
    not(descendant-or-self::*[self::img or self::input or self::br])
    ]
     [not(ancestor::*
             [count(.| //*[not(normalize-space((translate(., '&#xA0;', ''))))
                         and
                           not(descendant-or-self::*
                                  [self::img or self::input or self::br])
                          ]
                    )
             =
              count(//*[not(normalize-space((translate(., '&#xA0;', ''))))
                      and
                        not(descendant-or-self::*
                                 [self::img or self::input or self::br])
                        ]
                   )
              ]
          )
     ]
```

**Short XSLT-2.0 - based verification using variables**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
     xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
     <xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
     <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

     <xsl:variable name="vAllEmpty" select=
      "//*[not(normalize-space((translate(., '&#xA0;', ''))))
         and
           not(descendant-or-self::*
                 [self::img or self::input or self::br])

          ]"/>

     <xsl:variable name="vTopEmpty" select=
     "$vAllEmpty[not(ancestor::* intersect $vAllEmpty)]"/>

     <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
      <xsl:copy>
       <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
      </xsl:copy>
     </xsl:template>

     <xsl:template match="*[. intersect $vTopEmpty]"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This transformation copies every node "as-is" with the exception of any node that belongs to `$vTopEmpty` . The result is the correct and expected one:

```
<html>
   <a href="http://example.com">good</a>
   <br/>
   <img src="http://example.com/logo.png"/>
</html>
```

---

**III. Alternative solution (may require "multiple cleanups")**:

An alternative approach is not to attempt to specify the nodes to delete, but to specify the nodes to keep -- then the nodes to delete are the set difference between all nodes and the nodes to keep.

**The nodes to keep are selected by this XPath expression**:

```
  //node()
    [self::input or self::img or self::br
    or
     self::text()[normalize-space(translate(.,'&#xA0;',''))]
    ]
     /ancestor-or-self::node()
```

**Then the nodes to delete are**:

```
  //node()
     [not(count(.
              |
                //node() 
                   [self::input or self::img or self::br
                  or
                    self::text()[normalize-space(translate(.,'&#xA0;',''))]
                   ]
                    /ancestor-or-self::node()
                )
        =
         count(//node()
                  [self::input or self::img or self::br
                 or
                   self::text()[normalize-space(translate(.,'&#xA0;',''))]
                  ]
                   /ancestor-or-self::node()
               )
         )
     ]
```

**However, do note** that these are *all* nodes to delete and not only the "top nodes to delete". It is possible to express only the "top nodes to delete", but the resulting expression is rather complicated. If one attempts to delete all-nodes-to delete, there will be errors due to the fact that the descendants of the "top nodes to delete" follow them in document order.

Comment: Very well done! I'm going to have lots of fun digesting this answer.

Comment: @Xeoncross: You are welcome. I would be glad to answer your future questions :)

Answer (score 2):

So you want text nodes, `<br>` and `<img>`, as well as their ancestors?

You can get all br and img with `//br` and `//img`.

You can get all text nodes with `//text()`, and all non empty text nodes with `//text()[normalize-space()]`.  (although you might need something like `//text()[normalize-space(translate(., '&nbsp;', ''))]` to filter the `&nbsp;` text nodes if your xml parser doesn't already do that)

And you can get all parents with `ancestor-or-self::*`.

So the resulting expression is

```
//br/ancestor-or-self::* | //img/ancestor-or-self::* | //text()[normalize-space()]/ancestor-or-self::*
```

And shorter in XPath 2:

```
(//br | //img | //text()[normalize-space()])/ancestor-or-self::*
```

Comment: Why the downvote? It returns exactly the nodes xeoncross wants to keep. (except the //innput i forgot). And ancestor:: should be faster than descendant::

Comment: BeniBela, I think that using DOM (as required by the OP) it is possible to delete nodes and obtain the wanted resulting document. However I believe that just selecting the nodes to keep isn't directly helpful in constructing a new document with these nodes only -- this seem rather challenging, if possible at all. Expressing the set difference between all nodes and the nodes-to-keep inevitably results in a very complex (XPath 1.0 as implied by "DOM methods") expression -- see my answer (the alternative approach at the end) where I provide an XPath expression for this set difference.

Comment: I think I have seen an online XPath interpreter that does it (i.e. prints as result the whole document without the not-matched nodes). And it shouldn't be too difficult to enumerate all tags/nodes and print them sequentially iff they are in the result set. (printing without children, and treating open and closing tag as separate "node")

Comment: Printing is one thing, but creating an XML document (with DOM) with its nodes without duolication is a totally different thing. All this just shows why XSLT shines in expressing such transformations.

Comment: If you can print it, you can just run a xml parser on it afterwards. (and for me it would be easy, since I alway store the "DOM" tree as double linked list of tags with additional links between matching opening/closing tags. Then printing and creating the document is the same )

Comment: BeniBela, printing and re-parsing cause too much inefficiency as compared to deleting the nodes in-place. It is great that "for you it will be easy", but this fact isn't too-relevant to the OP's question.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried an XPath similar to this?

```
*[not(*) and not(text()[normalize-space()])]
```

With

- `not(*)` = no child element
- `text()[normalize-space()]` = Include nodes with non whitespace-text  (not inverses this)

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way to achieve needed result is usage of regular expressions with your text. With remark: you have to use this expression several times, as it is not greedy it deletes only lowest empty child nodes, so to delete all empty nodes we have to call the regex several times.

Here is the solution:

```
<?
$text = '<div class="empty">
    <div>&nbsp;</div>
    <div></div>
</div>
<a href="http://example.com">good</a>
<div>
    <p></p>
</div>
<br>
<img src="http://example.com/logo.png" />
<div></div>';

// recursive function
function recreplace($text)
{
    $restext = preg_replace("/<div(.*)?>((\s|&nbsp;)*|(\s|&nbsp;)*<p>(\s|&nbsp;)*<\/p>(\s|&nbsp;)*)*<\/div>/U", '', $text);
    if ($text != $restext) 
    {
        recreplace($restext);
    }
    else
    {
        return $restext;
    }
}

print recreplace($text);
?>
```

This code prints your desired result. If you need the regex can be edited, any other tags that should be count as empty (as `<p> </p>`) could be added in it.

With given example this function will call itself two times resultatively and the third time without any replace made - and that will be the result.