# php remove html tags that surround no content

Tags: php, html, regex, html-parsing

I'm displaying content (a string called $ps filled with html) that has been written in a wysiwyg editor (external css is not being used) and contains empty space such as

```
<p>

<span style="font-family: Calibri, sans-serif; font-size: 11pt;">
    <br></br>
</span>
<span style="font-size: 11pt; font-family: Calibri, sans-serif;">
</span>

</p>
```

which i want to remove using php (because I expect the authors to continue accidentally adding empty stuff).

So far, I have this highly inefficient code:

```
$ps = preg_replace('#class="(.*?)"#', '',$ps);
$ps = preg_replace('#style="(.*?)"#', '',$ps);
$ps = preg_replace('#<br\s*/*>#i', '',$ps);
$ps = preg_replace('#<span\s*/*>#i', '',$ps);
$ps = preg_replace('#<p>\s*</p>#i', '',$ps);
```

which is about half way good, leaving me with:

```
<p>

</p>
<p>

</p>
```

and I suspect it won't work reliably if the empty stuff looks a tad different.

Can you help me build a better solution I can easily implement? Perhaps a regex expression that works, unlike my attempts so far..

Thank you!

Comment: first things first (disregarding whether this is a good way to do this or not) preg_replace can take an array of regexes.  ie: `preg_replace(array('#class="(.*?)"#', '#style="(.*?)"#', '#<br\s*/*>#i', '#<span\s*/*>#i', '#<p>\s*</p>#i'), '',$ps);`

Comment: I think you should use [DOMXPath](http://docs.php.net/DOMXPath) to remove empty nodes. regular expressions are not good with HTML. Check these 2 SO solutions. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8603237/remove-empty-tags-from-a-xml-with-php and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11744454/xpath-to-recursively-remove-empty-dom-nodes

Comment: Parsing HTML with regexes is a recipe for sorrow.  When your user input doesn't match your expectations, your regexes will break.  What if your `<p></p>` tags are on different lines, for example?  Modifying HTML with regexes is even worse.  Use a proper HTML parser.

Comment: You may find useful my answer to a very similar question: [Remove all empty HTML tags?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5573115/433790)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use DOMDocument instead of regex :

```
$html = '<span style="font-family: Calibri, sans-serif; font-size: 11pt;">...';

$domd = new DOMDocument();
$domd->loadHTML($html);

$domx = new DOMXPath($domd);
$items = $domx->query("//*");

foreach($items as $item) {
  $item->removeAttribute("style");
  $item->removeAttribute("class");
}

echo $domd->saveHTML();
```

You can also remove empty nodes, or whatever else you need removing.

Comment: something like `if (trim($item->nodeValue) == '') $item->parentNode->removeChild($item);` might do it, though I havent tested

Comment: thanks everyone so far! This solution is almost complete. I now have trouble with Umlaute in $html and
    if (trim($item->nodeValue) == '') $item->parentNode->removeChild($item);
only removing the first/ some occurrences of empty nodes. I haven't figured out what this depends upon.

Comment: @user148585 You need to pay attention to what gets removed first, or run it through a few times.  If a span has an empty span in it then the internal span should get removed but the outer one probably wont be.

Comment: @wolffer-east could you help me with the recurrence, please? So far I've brutally done $domd2->loadHTML($domd->saveHTML()); and accordingly copied what followed but without success.

Answer (score 0):

In response to the comment from in @ovi's answer, because code blocks in comments are ugly

You could run it until it no longer removes anything from the set of elements.  This will drag on and on if it is a long document, but I guess it would work.

for example

```
$changed = true;
while ($changed = true){
  $changed = false;
  foreach($items as $item) {
    if (trim($item->nodeValue) == ''){
      $item->parentNode->removeChild($item);
      $changed = true;
    }
  }
}
```

I reiterate that this could take a comparitively long time.  Also, I haven't tested the `$item->parentNode->removeChild($item);` piece yet.

Comment: Thanks, I see what you mean. Unfortunately, removeChild somehow ends up trying to remove non-objects? Even if this loop is the only thing being done after the query..

Comment: unfortunately I'm no expert on domdocument manipulation. You can give `(trim($item->nodeValue) == '' && $child->nodeName != "#text")` a try.

Comment: that didn't do the trick unfortunately. Thank you so much for your help nevertheless!